# Days calculation in DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have DataFrame with clients' agreements like below:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2020-12-01', periods=5, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({ "ID" : ["1", "2", "1", "2", "2"], "Date": rng})
```

And I need to create new DataFrame with calculation based on above df:

1. New1 = amount of days from the first agreement until today (16.12)
2. New2 = amount of days from the last agreement until today (16.12)

To be more precision I need to create df like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Series.rsub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rsub.html) for subtract from right side with today and convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) and then aggregate by [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html) for [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) values per groups:

```
now = pd.to_datetime('today')

df = (df.assign(new = df['Date'].rsub(now).dt.days)
        .groupby('ID').agg(New1 = ('new', 'first'),
                           New2 = ('new', 'last')))
        .reset_index()
print (df)
  ID  New1  New2
0  1    15    13
1  2    14    11
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `groupby`:

```
New1 = pd.to_datetime('today') - df.groupby("ID")['Date'].min()
New2 = pd.to_datetime('today') - df.groupby("ID")['Date'].max()
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'ID': df['ID'].drop_duplicates(), 'New1': New1.tolist(), 'New2': New2.tolist()})
print(df2)
```

Output:

```
  ID    New1    New2
0  1 15 days 13 days
1  2 14 days 11 days
```